# Nuxt.js: How to use the same page with different URLs and switch the components to be displayed according to the URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to implement the following in Nuxt.js:

**1.Use the same page with different URLs.**

Specifically, I want to use `/pages/users/_userId.vue` with`/users/{userId}`, `/users/{userId}/follow` and `/users/{userId}/follower`.

I examined this and there were the following issues.
- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2693
But it was a little different from what I wanted to achieve.
I want to use the pass parameter for the query parameter.

**2.Identify the components to display by path parameters**
It would be quicker to have a look at the code here.

・/pages/users/_userId.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="user">
    <div class="user__contents">
      <div class="user__contents__main">
        <UserInfo/>
        <PostSection/> -> use if URL /users /{userId}
        <FollowSection/> -> use if URL /users/{userId}/follow
        <FollowerSection/> -> use if URL /users/{userId}/follower
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserInfo from '~/components/organisms/users/UserInfo'
import PostsSection from '~/components/organisms/users/PostsSection'
import FollowSection from '~/components/organisms/users/FollowSection'
import FollowerSection from '~/components/organisms/users/FollowerSection'
```

...

What should I do to achieve these?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the displayed components depends on the current route, you can use the router.
Namely using the nuxtjs nested routes feature. [(example of dynamic nested routes in nuxtjs docs)](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-nested-routes)

```
pages/
--| users/
-----| _id/
--------| follow.vue // contains FollowSection
--------| follower.vue // contains FollowerSection
--------| index.vue // contains UserProfile
-----| _id.vue
```

```
// users/_id.vue
<template>
  <div class="user">
    <div class="user__contents">
      <div class="user__contents__main">
        <UserInfo>
        <NuxtChild 
           :user="user"
           @custom-event="customEventHandler"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<template>
```

You can reuse the components as nested pages like that:

```
// pages/users/_id/follower.vue

<script>
 // don't create a template for the section
import FollowSection from '~/components/organisms/users/FollowSection'
export default FollowSection
</script>
```

Note that you don't need to import the child components in `_id.vue` because nuxt configure vue-router to do so. Also that you can pass props and send events to them like normal components.

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying to do this. Nuxt 2.14.6 `Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "{"  `. Doesnt seem to like exporting the import.

Comment: It should be `export default FollowSection` instead of `export FollowSection`

Comment: Hello! I'm reusing pages but I still need to set a parameter, like a prop ou data before instance starts somethins like

import index from "~/pages/blog/_category/index.vue"
const a = index
a.data().nome = "Maralhiva"
export default a


It didnt work but is there a way doing it?

Comment: @RobertoFonseca You can pass the data as a prop to `<nuxt-child :nome="nome">`.  This will work on page component which accept the `nome` prop

Comment: Does this reload the page?

Answer (score 2):

All your paths have a common prefix `users/`. So you can use the `pages/users/_.vue` component to match any path starting with the `users/` that was not matched to any other component.

In this component you can examine `$nuxt.$route.params.pathMatch` to decide, which subcomponent to show. It will contain part of path after `users/`:

```
<template>
  <div class="user">
    <div class="user__contents">
      <div class="user__contents__main">
        <UserInfo />
        <PostSection v-if="/^\d+$/.test(path)" />
        <FollowSection v-else-if="/^\d+\/follow$/.test(path)" />
        <FollowerSection v-else-if="/^\d+\/follower$/.test(path)" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    path() {
      return this.$nuxt.$route.params.pathMatch;
    },
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of one page , you can create individual page by setting your project directory structrue like this . It will more easy to handle and modify

```
pages/
--| users/
-----| _id/
--------| follow.vue
--------| follower.vue
-----| _id.vue
```

Comment: That is not an optimal solution. Having the same .vue page twice is difficult to maintain.